# Why virtualenv relies on the global python instead of the local one, after being pulled?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I pulled (git) a python project which was created (by me on another computer) using virtualenv. So, the python library is actually in a local directory (e.g., `fila_env/bin/python`) in this project. After pulling it, I can locate that (see the tree below). However, when I activate the environment (using `source fila_env/bin/activate`), the python on this machine is being used instead of the virtualenv's:

```
(fila_env) username@ASCSC-645A:~/CODES/.../myProject$ which python
>>> /usr/bin/python
```

I googled around but I couldn't find a good solution to this. I would like to know:

1. How I can assure that if someone pulls this project, they will only
   use the provided python library, and not their own python.
2. Is this a correct approach to create a virtualenv, and push the entire project (including the virtualenv) to the cloud?

Here are some more info:

```
├── yyyyyyExample.py
├── fila_env
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── activate
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── python
│   │   ├── python2 -> python
│   │   ├── python2.7 -> python
│   │   ├── python-config
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── wheel
│   ├── include
│   │   └── python2.7 -> /usr/include/python2.7
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── python2.7
│   ├── local
│   │   ├── bin -> .../fila_env/bin
│   │   ├── include -> .../fila_env/include
│   │   └── lib -> .../fila_env/lib
│   ├── pip-selfcheck.json
│   └── share
│       ├── jupyter
│       └── man
└── xxxxxxExample.py
```

Comment: As an alternative: if you have an explicit (C)Python dependency, you may be better off packaging it as a Conda package.

Comment: My answer to question to would be "no". Specify any dependencies in another way, or just try to completely avoid them (do you *really* require a specific Python version? What version exactly, and why?).

Comment: If you activate our local environment it will try to fetch pip packages from local, if package not found on local environment it will take it from global. You can create a requirments.txt including all the pip packages. Everyone who make a clone of our project will just do a pip install on local environment

Comment: @LavanyaPant all of those packages were installed using a local pip. The requirements.txt file is also there but I only posted a summarized list.

Comment: @Azim We should avoid push virtual env to git. If someone want to install it locally he/she should create virtual env and install your package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot and you shouldn't, If I use 32-bit Linux and your virtualenv has been created on 64-bit Windows (or vice versa) your python binary certainly will not work for me.
2. Again, no. virtualenv is a developer's tool, not a distribution tool. For distribution you should consider [sdist/egg/wheel](https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/index.html), or creating platform-dependent binaries with [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/), [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FrontPage) or similar tools.